# How to prevent personal information showing in network request through xhr fetch response

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, security

I'm building a simple scheduling module where I'll allow anyone to come to a website to submit an appointment through the scheduler.

In the scheduler module I have the following:

1. Appointments are in 30 min increments so for example if an appointment is booked at 9:00AM it'll run from 9:00AM - 9:30AM.
2. I'm storing personal information from the appointment that got scheduled from user input such as phone number, email address, full name
3. After the user submits a schedule, I run a SQL select statement where it fetches all the data from the scheduled appointments from the  MYSQL DB onto the scheduler component so users can see what appointments are already taken and what slots are available at the specified time.

This works great and everything but I'm a little concerned when I push this to production I noticed that in my network requests, I can see all data that got fetched from the DB. Can this be a security concern for allowing anyone from going to the network requests to see the fetched data that contains the personal information?

So my question is how do I prevent this?

Here is my code:

**ReactJS**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import appController from '../../controllers/appController';

import Scheduleservice from '../../services/Scheduleservice';
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';
import Moment from 'moment';
import AOS from 'aos'; // Animate on scroll

import {
  ScheduleComponent,
  ResourcesDirective,
  ResourceDirective,
  ViewsDirective,
  ViewDirective,
  Inject,
  TimelineViews,
  Resize,
  DragAndDrop,
  TimelineMonth,
  Day,
  Week,
  WorkWeek,
  Month,
  Agenda
} from '@syncfusion/ej2-react-schedule';

import { DateTimePickerComponent } from '@syncfusion/ej2-react-calendars';
import { DropDownListComponent } from '@syncfusion/ej2-react-dropdowns';
import { DataManager, WebApiAdaptor, ODataV4Adaptor } from '@syncfusion/ej2-data';


//import * as dataSource from './datasource.json';

class Voipcall extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.dataManager = new DataManager({
      url: '/api/selectSchedule',
      adaptor: new WebApiAdaptor,
    })
    this.state = {
      scheduleData: [],
      employeeData: [
        {
          Text: 'Facility Appointment',
          Id: 1,
          GroupId: 1,
          Color: '#9e5fff',
          Designation: 'Schedule an appointment',
        },
      ],
    };
  }

  onActionBegin(args) {
    //console.log('data sent after insertion', args);

    if(args.requestType === 'eventCreate' || args.requestType === 'eventChange') {
      let data = args.data instanceof Array ? args.data[0] : args.data;

      //console.log('Original Data', data);

      // If Subject is blank
      if(data.Subject !== 'Add title') {
        //console.log('subject is blank')

        // Format the data Role Id is guest which is 3
        let insertData = {
          RoleId: undefined ? "3" : "3",
          Subject: data.Subject === undefined ? null : data.Subject,
          FullName: data.fullName === undefined ? null : data.fullName,
          Resident: data.resident === undefined ? null : data.resident,
          CommunicationInfo: data.communicationInfo === undefined ? null : data.communicationInfo,
          CommunicationMethod: data.communicationMethod === undefined ? null : data.communicationMethod,
          Email: data.email === undefined ? null : data.email,
          Phone: data.phone === undefined ? null : data.phone,
          StartTime: data.StartTime === undefined ? null : appController.converttoISO(data.StartTime),
          EndTime: data.EndTime === undefined ? null : appController.converttoISO(data.EndTime),
          Description: data.Description === undefined ? null : data.Description
        }

      console.log('data insertion', insertData)

      // Insert Schedule Data into DB
      const insertSchedule = Scheduleservice.insertSchedule(insertData);


      // Refresh the scheduler
      this.props.history.push({
        pathname: '/voipCall',
        });
      }
    }
}

onEventRendered(args) {

  console.log("Start time ", Moment(args.data.startTime).format());
  console.log("End time ", Moment(args.data.endTime).format());

  if(args.element.innerText !== 'Not Available') {
    args.element.style.backgroundColor = '#0CA6C4';
    args.element.innerText = 'Appointment Booked';
  }

  if(args.element.innerText === 'Not Available') {
    args.element.style.backgroundColor = '#ccc';
  }

  if(args.element.innerText === 'Appointment Booked') {
    args.element.style.backgroundColor = '#09A6CA';
  }
}

  getEmployeeName(value) {
    return value.resourceData[value.resource.textField];
  }
  getEmployeeImage(value) {
    let resourceName = this.getEmployeeName(value);
    return resourceName.toLowerCase();
  }
  getEmployeeDesignation(value) {
    return value.resourceData.Designation;
  }
  resourceHeaderTemplate(props) {
    return (
      <div className='template-wrap'>
        <div className='employee-category'>
          <div
            className={'employee-image ' + this.getEmployeeImage(props)}
          ></div>
          <div className='employee-name'>{this.getEmployeeName(props)}</div>
          <div className='employee-designation'>
            {this.getEmployeeDesignation(props)}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  editorTemplate(props) {
    return props !== undefined ? (
      <table
        className='custom-event-editor'
        style={{ width: '100%', cellpadding: '5' }}
      >
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td className='e-textlabel'>Meeting Name</td>
            <td style={{ colspan: '4' }}>
              <input
                id='Summary'
                className='e-field e-input'
                type='text'
                name='Subject'
                style={{ width: '100%' }}
                placeholder='Event Name...'
              />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td className='e-textlabel'>Full Name</td>
            <td style={{ colspan: '4' }}>
              <input
                id='fullName'
                className='e-field e-input'
                type='text'
                name='fullName'
                style={{ width: '100%' }}
                placeholder='Full Name'
              />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td className='e-textlabel'>Resident Requesting to Speak to</td>
            <td style={{ colspan: '4' }}>
              <input
                id='resident'
                className='e-field e-input'
                type='text'
                name='resident'
                style={{ width: '100%' }}
                placeholder='Resident you wish to speak to...'
              />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td className='e-textlabel'>Preferred Method of Communication</td>
            <td style={{ colspan: '4' }}>
              <DropDownListComponent
                id='communicationMethod'
                placeholder='Choose Method of Communication'
                data-name='communicationMethod'
                className='e-field'
                style={{ width: '100%' }}
                dataSource={['Zoom', 'Skype', 'Facetime', 'Viber']}
              ></DropDownListComponent>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td className='e-textlabel'>Communication Information</td>
            <td style={{ colspan: '4' }}>
              <input
                id='communicationInfo'
                className='e-field e-input'
                type='text'
                name='communicationInfo'
                style={{ width: '100%' }}
                placeholder='Communication ID'
              />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td className='e-textlabel'>Email Address</td>
            <td style={{ colspan: '4' }}>
              <input
                id='email'
                className='e-field e-input'
                type='email'
                name='email'
                style={{ width: '100%' }}
                placeholder='Email Address'
              />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td className='e-textlabel'>Phone Number ex: 123456789</td>
            <td style={{ colspan: '4' }}>
              <input
                id='phone'
                className='e-field e-input'
                type='tel'
                name='phone'
                style={{ width: '100%' }}
                placeholder='Phone Number'
              />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td className='e-textlabel'>From</td>
            <td style={{ colspan: '4' }}>
              <DateTimePickerComponent
                id='StartTime'
                format='MM/dd/yy hh:mm a'
                data-name='StartTime'
                value={new Date(props.startTime || props.StartTime)}
                className='e-field'
                disabled
              ></DateTimePickerComponent>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td className='e-textlabel'>To</td>
            <td style={{ colspan: '4' }}>
              <DateTimePickerComponent
                id='EndTime'
                format='MM/dd/yy hh:mm a'
                data-name='EndTime'
                value={new Date(props.endTime || props.EndTime)}
                className='e-field'
                disabled
              ></DateTimePickerComponent>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td className='e-textlabel'>Reason</td>
            <td style={{ colspan: '4' }}>
              <textarea
                id='Description'
                className='e-field e-input'
                name='Description'
                rows={3}
                cols={50}
                style={{
                  width: '100%',
                  height: '60px !important',
                  resize: 'vertical',
                }}
              ></textarea>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    ) : (
      <div></div>
    );
  }

  fetchSchedule = async () => {
    const selectSchedule = await Scheduleservice.selectSchedule();

    await this.setState({
      scheduleData: selectSchedule
    })

    //console.log("Schedule Data State is ", this.state.scheduleData);
    //console.log("Local Datasource is ", dataSource.scheduleData);
    //console.log("state is ", this.state)

  }

  componentDidMount = async () => {
    await this.fetchSchedule();
  }

  render() {
    const { match, location, history } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className='voipContainer'>
        <div className='fluid-container'>
          <div className='container'>
            <div className='row'>
              <div className='schedule-control-section'>
                <div className='col-lg-12 control-section'>
                  <div className='control-wrapper drag-sample-wrapper'>
                    <div className='schedule-container'>
                      <ScheduleComponent
                        //ref={(schedule) => (this.scheduleObj = schedule)}
                        //ref={(schedule) => console.log("Schedule Data is", schedule)}
                        cssClass='block-events'
                        width='100%'
                        height='650px'
                        selectedDate={new Date()}
                        minDate={appController.previousDay(new Date())}
                        showTimeIndicator={false}
                        currentView='Day'
                        resourceHeaderTemplate={this.resourceHeaderTemplate.bind(
                          this
                        )}
                        actionBegin={this.onActionBegin.bind(this)}
                        eventSettings={{
                          dataSource: this.dataManager,
                        }}
                        eventRendered={this.onEventRendered.bind(this)}
                        // group={{
                        //   enableCompactView: false,
                        //   resources: ['Employee'],
                        // }}
                        //readonly={true}
                        timeScale={{ enable: true, interval: 30, slotCount: 1 }}
                        editorTemplate={this.editorTemplate.bind(this)}
                      >
                        <ResourcesDirective>
                          <ResourceDirective
                            field='EmployeeId'
                            title='Employees'
                            name='Employee'
                            allowMultiple={true}
                            dataSource={this.state.employeeData}
                            textField='Text'
                            idField='Id'
                            colorField='Color'
                          ></ResourceDirective>
                        </ResourcesDirective>
                        <ViewsDirective>
                          <ViewDirective option='Day' />
                          <ViewDirective option='TimelineDay' />
                        </ViewsDirective>
                        <Inject
                          services={[
                            Day, Week, WorkWeek, Month, Agenda
                          ]}
                        />
                      </ScheduleComponent>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(Voipcall);
```

**MYSQL Statement**

```js
var db = require('../dbconnection');

var schedule = {
  selectSchedule: function (data, callback) {
    db.query(
      'select Id, Role_Id, Subject, Location, StartTime, EndTime, Description, Owner, Priority, Recurrence, RecurrenceType, RecurrenceTypeCount, Reminder, Categorize, CustomStyle, AllDay, RecurrenceStartDate, RecurrenceEndDate, RecurrenceRule, StartTimeZone, EndTimeZone, IsBlock, isSlotAvailable, FullName, Resident, CommunicationMethod, CommunicationInfo, Email, Phone, Reason from schedule',
      callback
    );
  },
  insertSchedule: function(data, callback) {
    db.query('insert schedule set Role_Id=?, Subject=?, FullName=?, Resident=?, CommunicationMethod=?, CommunicationInfo=?, Email=?, Phone=?, Reason=?, IsBlock=?, StartTime=?, EndTime=?', [data.RoleId, data.Subject, data.FullName, data.Resident, data.CommunicationMethod, data.CommunicationInfo, data.Email, data.Phone, data.Description, "true", data.StartTime, data.EndTime], callback)

    //console.log('data got sent to backend', data);
  }
};

module.exports = schedule;
```

Network Request Screenshot along with JSON Reponse:

[image]

```js
[
   {
      "Id":1,
      "Role_Id":null,
      "Subject":"Bering Sea Gold DB Test",
      "Location":"chn",
      "StartTime":"2020-09-23T09:00:00",
      "EndTime":"2020-09-23T10:30:00",
      "Description":"",
      "Owner":1,
      "Priority":null,
      "Recurrence":1,
      "RecurrenceType":null,
      "RecurrenceTypeCount":null,
      "Reminder":null,
      "Categorize":"1,2",
      "CustomStyle":null,
      "AllDay":"false",
      "RecurrenceStartDate":null,
      "RecurrenceEndDate":null,
      "RecurrenceRule":"FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=2;COUNT=10",
      "StartTimeZone":null,
      "EndTimeZone":null,
      "IsBlock":"",
      "isSlotAvailable":null,
      "FullName":null,
      "Resident":null,
      "CommunicationMethod":null,
      "CommunicationInfo":null,
      "Email":null,
      "Phone":null,
      "Reason":null
   },
   {
      "Id":2,
      "Role_Id":null,
      "Subject":"Not Available",
      "Location":null,
      "StartTime":"2020-08-01T03:00:00.000Z",
      "EndTime":"2020-08-01T09:00:00.000Z",
      "Description":null,
      "Owner":null,
      "Priority":null,
      "Recurrence":0,
      "RecurrenceType":null,
      "RecurrenceTypeCount":null,
      "Reminder":null,
      "Categorize":null,
      "CustomStyle":null,
      "AllDay":null,
      "RecurrenceStartDate":null,
      "RecurrenceEndDate":null,
      "RecurrenceRule":"FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1;",
      "StartTimeZone":null,
      "EndTimeZone":null,
      "IsBlock":"true",
      "isSlotAvailable":null,
      "FullName":null,
      "Resident":null,
      "CommunicationMethod":null,
      "CommunicationInfo":null,
      "Email":null,
      "Phone":null,
      "Reason":null
   },
   {
      "Id":22,
      "Role_Id":3,
      "Subject":"Test Appointment 1",
      "Location":null,
      "StartTime":"2020-09-24T14:30:00.000Z",
      "EndTime":"2020-09-24T15:00:00.000Z",
      "Description":null,
      "Owner":null,
      "Priority":null,
      "Recurrence":0,
      "RecurrenceType":null,
      "RecurrenceTypeCount":null,
      "Reminder":null,
      "Categorize":null,
      "CustomStyle":null,
      "AllDay":null,
      "RecurrenceStartDate":null,
      "RecurrenceEndDate":null,
      "RecurrenceRule":null,
      "StartTimeZone":null,
      "EndTimeZone":null,
      "IsBlock":"true",
      "isSlotAvailable":null,
      "FullName":"John Doe",
      "Resident":"Alex West",
      "CommunicationMethod":"Facetime",
      "CommunicationInfo":"test@test.com",
      "Email":"test@test.com",
      "Phone":"999999999",
      "Reason":"This is a test Module."
   },
   {
      "Id":23,
      "Role_Id":3,
      "Subject":"Test Appointment 2",
      "Location":null,
      "StartTime":"2020-09-24T18:30:00.000Z",
      "EndTime":"2020-09-24T19:00:00.000Z",
      "Description":null,
      "Owner":null,
      "Priority":null,
      "Recurrence":0,
      "RecurrenceType":null,
      "RecurrenceTypeCount":null,
      "Reminder":null,
      "Categorize":null,
      "CustomStyle":null,
      "AllDay":null,
      "RecurrenceStartDate":null,
      "RecurrenceEndDate":null,
      "RecurrenceRule":null,
      "StartTimeZone":null,
      "EndTimeZone":null,
      "IsBlock":"true",
      "isSlotAvailable":null,
      "FullName":"Jason Stride",
      "Resident":"Chris Thomson",
      "CommunicationMethod":"Facetime",
      "CommunicationInfo":"test2@test.com",
      "Email":"test2@test.com",
      "Phone":"999999999",
      "Reason":"This is test appointment 2"
   }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three things to keep in mind:

1. use https:// to deliver data to your users' browsers. It's very hard for cybercreeps to intercept data delivered that way.
2. make sure you each user receives only their own data, or data they're entitled to view.  Do not rely on your front end code to conceal user A's data from user B. It won't work because any user can look at your requests and responses in the Network tab of devtools. You usually do this with a hard-to-guess session token tied to each logged-in user.
3. Don't let your web server return any data you don't want the user of a browser to see.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. In production I'm using https but I think what I'll end up doing is only selecting the ID from my backend and displaying it to all users to see rather than personal information, that should still show on the scheduler. Is that okay to do?

Comment: Actually I got it. I just modified my select statement on my backend to only select the ID to still show on the scheduler and removed any select statements containing personal information to other users.

Comment: Yes, that's it. Always know the ID of the user, and always use `WHERE ID = ?` for the ID you know, when you're handing REST endpoints to deliver data to your app.